# cannot execute command after logging in with expect

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

    set timeout 60

    spawn ssh -X user@login.domain.co.uk

    expect "Password:"
    # Send the password, and then wait for a shell prompt.
    send "password\r"
    exp_continue
    expect "user*"
    send "ls -la\r"
```

however I get the following:

```
Password: command returned bad code: -101
    while executing
"exp_continue"
    (file "./hpclogin.sh" line 10)
```

If I remove the `exp_continue` i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

    set timeout 60

    spawn ssh -X user@login.domain.co.uk

    expect "Password:"
    # Send the password, and then wait for a shell prompt.
    send "password\r"
    expect "user*"
    send "ls -la\r"
```

I can log in successfully, however the `ls -la` command does not get executed. Is there something wrong with the flow-control of my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exp_continue` is only useful inside an `expect` block. For example:

```
spawn ssh -X user@example.com
expect {
    "continue connecting (yes/no)? " {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue"
    }
    "Password:"
}
send "password\r"
```

I think you're not seeing the `ls` output because you're not expecting to see anything after to send it. Depending on your workflow, here are 2 thoughts:

1. add the command as arguments to `ssh`

   ```
   spawn ssh -X user@example.com ls -la
   expect {
       "continue connecting (yes/no)? " {
           send "yes\r"
           exp_continue"
       }
       "Password:"
   }
   send "password\r"
   expect eof
   ```
2. expect a prompt after the command, and log out afterwards

   ```
   spawn ssh -X user@example.com
   expect {
       "continue connecting (yes/no)? " {
           send "yes\r"
           exp_continue"
       }
       "Password:"
   }
   send "password\r"
   expect $theprompt
   send "ls -la\r"
   expect $theprompt
   send "exit\r"
   expect eof
   ```

Of course, this would be much simpler using ssh keys:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id user@example.com
ssh -X user@example.com ls -la
```

Comment: thanks for answering. FYI I am going to be using the keygen method as that worked for me too, and much more convenient.